# SEDE did not update

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

SEDE [currently states](https://data.stackexchange.com/) it was updated 11 minutes ago:

[image]

However this does not appear to be the case, as [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/693892):

```
select 
  max(creationdate) [last action],
  datediff(day, max(creationdate), getdate()) [days ago]
from posthistory
```

When run on SO, currently yields:

```
last action         days ago 
------------------- -------- 
2017-07-02 05:18:54 8
```

Which suggests that no data exists for the past 7 days.

I had originally just assumed this was an issue on all sites but the comment below points out (and I've confirmed) that it's not. So far I haven't found any other sites that exhibit this behavior besides SO (including MSO, which is up-to-date).

Comment: When running on MSE it returns the `MAX(CreationSate)` as `2017-07-10 17:16:34`

Comment: @adamlear I don't follow the status by design. Do you mean SEDE is not supposed to update or that when partial updates took place the outcome will be as the OP noticed or did you maybe pick the wrong tag? In the latter case there is coffee for you in the Tavern ...

Comment: @rene See Nick's answer. The date is updated as DBs are refreshed, going from newest site to oldest. The display is confusing, but "by design" if you tilt your head and squint a little. (Update failure over the weekend is a separate issue and not what's being reported here.)

Comment: I closed my eyes and now I see what you mean .. ;) ... I'll take the coffee ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The job failed this weekend because the READ UNCOMMITTED gods were against us. Luckily we sacrificed some regexes on the pillar of please-let-this-workiness to the hamster gods and it's re-running. It takes many hours.

The screen isn't wrong, but I totally see how it's misleading here. *Some* data was refreshed just now, but Stack Overflow hasn't been hit yet, it'll take several more hours to finish. The process goes from newest sites to oldest (meaning Stack Overflow is last), I'll be keeping an eye on it.

Comment: Those READ UNCOMMITTED gods are very particular about their regexes, it seems.  Good to know.

Comment: [SO's data looks to be up to date now.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRCzEqkCoiM)