# Brief maintenances planned for Sat, July 22, 2017 at 00:01 UTC (Fri July 21, 8pm US/Eastern)

Tags: discussion, announcements

> **Update: The July 21st maintenance is complete.** All systems are back to normal now.

There will be a service degradation for up to 20 minutes shortly after Sat, July 22, 2017 at 00:00 UTC (which is Fri, July 21 at 8pm in NYC). During that time job adverts will still display, job listings will still work, questions and answers will still display. **However the site will be "read only," i.e. people won’t be able to add/edit new job listings, apply for jobs, post/edit questions/comments/answers, upvotes/reputations won’t change, etc.** We don't love having to do this, but it is unavoidable and will prevent larger problems in the future. This should not be very disruptive since the site will still work for the majority of our users. Users that are affected will see a warning banner. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Here's a helpful [timezone converter.](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=StackOverflow+maintenance&iso=20170721T2001&p1=179&ah=1)

As described [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298151/brief-maintenances-planned-for-sat-july-8-22-2017-both-at-1400-utc-10am-us), we were running out of our "backup datacenter" in Colorado while maintenance was performed in our primary datacenter (known as "NY").  This is the "fail-back" to normal... or as we call it, this is our "success-over".

[See our previous post for details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298151/brief-maintenances-planned-for-sat-july-8-22-2017-both-at-1400-utc-10am-us). If you have any questions, please post them below!

Comment: Should this post be upvoted to inform this notice to more and more users?

Comment: @JaideepKhare it is your vote. If you find the post useful and clear, vote it up. If you think it is *meh* don't vote. If you hate down time, vote it down. Optionally leave a comment to explain in that case why the maintenance shouldn't take place or be postponed or whatever your problem is with the post in its current revision. It is tagged [tag:featured] so it will show up on all sites network wide anyway.

Comment: My sympathies to the chap who drew the short straw and has to do server maintenance at 8 PM on a Friday.

Comment: You forgot to tell which sites of the SE network

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz All sites. All products (Talent, question and answer, etc).

Comment: @CodyGray considering at least a few SO employees are remote, or at least located in other timezones, it might be in normal working hours.

Comment: Upvoted in appreciation of the staff's hard work!