# Chat search not returning messages posted after July 8

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-search

For some reason, chat searches are not returning any results newer than July 8 at about 2:05 PM UTC. [This example search](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=smokedetector&room=11540) pinpoints the issue.

The problem appears to be caused by the recent datacenter transfers. The time cutoff is apparently defined by the time the [failover to Colorado](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/162645665344/data-center-failover-july-8-2017) occurred, and search began returning missing results after the [failback to New York](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/163188390264/data-center-failback-july-21-2017). It seems as if the search engine is running on outdated indexes that were not updated since the Colorado failover.

Can someone look into this?

---

**Edit:** This issue appears to be isolated to the `chat.stackexchange.com` server. The other two chat servers are unaffected.

Comment: Just FYI: Chat search  indexes are up to date on [SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cv-pls&room=41570) and [MSE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=SmokeDetector&user=&room=1037)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had an [issue with our scheduler service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353675/17373) crashing due to the [failover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298671/brief-maintenances-planned-for-sat-july-22-2017-at-0001-utc-fri-july-21-8pm) last night. The scheduler has been restarted and your example search appears to have recent results now.

Comment: Any chance to add some alert to notify you when such crash occurs, so that you might restart it before it cause such problems?

Comment: already added to our followup items. Its our biggest pile of tech debt right now, needs a full replacement as it keeps causing issues.

Comment: But it worked for years without a problem. What changed?

Comment: Also, do you have the power to mark this bug report as [tag:status-completed]?