# What do votes on official announcements mean?

Tags: discussion, voting, meta

Since voting has a different meaning on Meta, what does it mean if someone upvotes an official announcement? Further more, why does [this question](/q/295285/350567) even have a downvote? Why is [this question](/q/290662/350567) heavily downvoted? I'm confused.

Comment: Why do you think the voting has a different meaning on announcements? It still a meta post and people still show their agreement and disagreement. Just because SE announces something it doesn't mean that everyone must like (and upvote) it.

Comment: @Tom the difference is the author is not just a random ordinary user, it's SE employee who can ban you on spot, that's intimidating. :)

Comment: About the second example: the comments even explain why that post was downvoted. How can that be confusing?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd They make their money with a community of volunteers, so I don't think the ban people for disagreeing with them.

Comment: @Tom of course, you know it, I know it, but I suspect great many users are not sure enough, so they think twice before downvoting.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's maybe correct, but how is that related to this question here? OP asked about the meaning of votes on announcements and wondered why there are downvotes at all. Or do you mean that downvotes might occur more often if the same post wouldn't be an official announcement and users might not be intimidated? Yes, that might be correct :).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd What?? A CM is gonna ban me for downvoting them?

Comment: @Uni no no, of course not. Just take away your keys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upvote on official announcement means I like what's being announced, usually.

Even if I don't really like it, I might still upvote since the team spent time on something, and that's something worthy.

As for downvotes, if I really dislike what's being announced I'll downvote to express this. Announcement with negative score means the community does not accept whatever is being introduced there, and it's vital feedback for the team. They might even reconsider the decision.

As for the single downvote on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295285/brief-outage-planned-for-wed-may-3-2017-at-8pm-us-eastern-0000-utc-like-a) (with 197 upvotes),  it's just noise; it does not mean anything. Someone might dislike SE making such an outage, or someone just downvoted random keys. We can't know, and shouldn't really waste time trying to figure this out.

Comment: I added another example post.

Comment: @iDebug exactly like I said, it means the new feature (“announcement” Tag for Direct Communication From the Team) is not welcome by the community. Users just don't like the idea and don't want it. Think it even helped. as far as I know that tag was still not added.

Comment: I just dislike outages. How dare you to call my vote noise!

Comment: @rene I am the Master of Noise!